# Jenkins not executing the build script

Tags: jenkins, hudson, sh

Jenkins is not executing the build script. what might be the problem here. I have a script like `/bin/sh /apple/orange/grape -t all -i`. all is not recognize here. Is this anything to do with environmental variable or something?

```
Building remotely on ..... in workspace /var/hudson/workspace/build
[Build] $ /bin/sh /tmp/hudson5936377040956096308.sh
[Build] $ /bin/sh /tmp/hudson1897855282333303575.sh
/bin/sh: all: No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Thanks for any help:
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't explicitly write `/bin/sh` in Jenkins "execute shell" build step. Only supply the command as you would from console:

`/apple/orange/grape -t all -i`